# Difficulty formulating optimisation problem according to DCP rules cvxpy

Tags: python, cvxpy, cvx

I'm trying to calculate the position of a target over time according to relative range and angle measurements from static anchors. For that I'm trying to formalise the problem with the same formulation as the following image.

[image: Formulation]

```
def solve_task10(sim, mu):
    x = cp.Variable((T, 2))

    cost = 0
    for t in range(1, T):
        # sum((|x-ak| - r)^2)
        range_differences = 0
        for i in range(4):
            range_, angle, velocity = sim.get_anchor_stamped_measurment(i, t)
            range_differences += cp.square(cp.norm(x[t] - sim.anchors[i]) - range_)

        # |v_est - v|^2
        v_estimated = (
            x[t] - x[t - 1]
        )  # Difference between x at time t and x at time t-1
        velocity_difference = mu * cp.square(cp.norm(v_estimated - velocity))

        cost += range_differences + velocity_difference

    objective = cp.Minimize(cost)
    constraints = [x[0] == np.array([0, 0])]
    problem = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)
    problem.solve(solver=cp.ECOS)

    return x.value
```

The issue I'm encountering is on:

```
range_differences += cp.square(cp.norm(x[t] - sim.anchors[i]) - range_)
```

How can i reformulate the problem to be DCP compliant?

Comment: Maybe you can be saved by the + in the subscript, which I think suggests that you wanted ``cp.square(cp.pos(cp.norm(x[t] - sim.anchors[i]) - range_))``

Answer (score 0):

cp.square(cp.pos(cp.norm(x[t] - sim.anchors[i]) - range_)) solvesthe problem